# Long primitive or AtomicLong for a counter?

Tags: java, performance, java.util.concurrent

I have a need for a counter of type `long` with the following requirements/facts:

- Incrementing the counter should take as little time as possible.
- The counter will only be written to by one thread.
- Reading from the counter will be done in another thread.
- The counter will be incremented regularly (as much as a few thousand times per second), but will only be read once every five seconds.
- Precise accuracy isn't essential, only a rough idea of the size of the counter is good enough.
- The counter is never cleared, decremented.

Based upon these requirements, how would you choose to implement your counter? As a simple `long`, as a `volatile long` or using an `AtomicLong`? Why?

At the moment I have a `volatile long` but was wondering whether another approach would be better. I am also incrementing my long by doing `++counter` as opposed to `counter++`. Is this really any more efficient (as I have been led to believe elsewhere) because there is no assignment being done?

Comment: volatile should be fine, since the contract states that every read on a volatile variable comes after the lock release of a previous write.

Comment: If you're only updating it a few thousand times per second and using a non-embedded processor, the difference is irrelevant; you can do millions of `AtomicLong` updates per second on most any machine these days.  Still, I agree that `volatile` should be enough.  You could encode both at once and check how often they match (and when they don't how far they're off) if you wanted to be sure.

Comment: @Riduidel we are counting incoming packets of data, and I we don't really mind whether the number is 12,345,678 or if it is slightly late at 12,345,602

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Given these sets of requirements, I *think* that a `volatile` long should be sufficient. The counter wouldn't be incorrect with a non-`volatile` long, but the reader might be reading stale information in that case.

One problem is that reads and writes to a `long` are [not *required* to be atomic](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.7), by the [JVM specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/index.html) if it is not declared `volatile`. That would mean that the reading thread could get a pretty much fictive value if it reads the value while the writing thread has updated one part of the value, but not the other one.

The difference between `++counter` and `counter++` is *probably* irrelevant, as the JVM will realize that the value of the expression is not used any more and the two are equivalent in this case.

Answer (score 5):

In Java 8, use LongAdder which is even better than AtomicLong where thread contention is high.

LongAdder JavaDoc:

> This class is usually preferable to AtomicLong when multiple threads update a common sum that is used for purposes such as collecting statistics, not for fine-grained synchronization control. Under low update contention, the two classes have similar characteristics. But under high contention, expected throughput of this class is significantly higher, at the expense of higher space consumption.

Comment: Contention is not high. Only one thread will be writing to it.

Answer (score 0):

what's the uptime requirement for your program?  Could you make do with an un-volatile int and racy-reads?

Comment: Uptime is as long as possible - this is running inside a server.

Answer (score 0):

10^4 increments / second is 1 every 100 usec. Efficiency is not an issue, but atomicity might be. You might have 2 copies of it, and when it is read, if they are not equal, read again.

Answer (score 0):

This [article](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t19676.html) talks about the possible ways to implement a counter 
I think this implementation should work for you

```
class LessNaiveVolatieIdGenerator {
private static volatile long id = 0;
public static long nextId() {
    long nextId = (id = id + 1); // or nextId = id++;
    return nextId;
}
```

}